# UpdateTip logs appear in debug.log unsolicitedly

Tags: logging

I'm running Bitcoin core daemon v0.17 on Ubuntu 18.04.

```
bitcoind -daemon -debug=addrman
```

Why do I receive UpdateTip logging in `~/.bitcoin/debug.log`?

> 2018-11-16T15:54:18Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000002d2353cdb7fa05bb8f81a2afb0f7d4f56a2fe546d3f91c height=521925 version=0x20000000 log2_work=88.768551 tx=315301499 date='2018-05-09T15:07:29Z' progress=0.890480 cache=11.4MiB(86353txo)
>
> 2018-11-16T15:54:18Z UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000000089d2f02570814347b4dac2b16eb9a1c9fac2d46e218fe height=521926 version=0x20000000 log2_work=88.768598 tx=315303612 date='2018-05-09T15:12:11Z' progress=0.890486 cache=12.2MiB(93273txo)
>
> 2018-11-16T15:54:18Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000000eb79a519b462b48fe02b4e4061ff18fb473eadba174b7 height=521927 version=0x20000000 log2_work=88.768645 tx=315305269 date='2018-05-09T15:21:55Z' progress=0.890491 cache=12.8MiB(97831txo)

It is just simply annoying since I want to check logs of Addrman only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn out the validation.cpp is performing many checks and they use LogPrintf() instead of logging tag.

So by default the debug.log always include them.